# How to add width and height to image

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I don't know much about coding, so could you help me with the right code to specify the width (285px) and height(143px) for this image?

```
$html .= '<img class="' . esc_attr( $args['thumb_align'] ) . ' rpwe-thumb" src="' . esc_url( $image ) . '" alt="' .  esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '">';
```

Many thanks!

Comment: How is this JavaScript in any way? This is all PHP

Comment: @MadaraUchiha but you died..

Comment: @Sidsec9 Or maybe you just dreamt it?

Comment: Why not just `<img src="..." width="..." height="...">`?

Comment: i have add answer both type will work

Answer (score 1):

add an id parameter into your image tag the simplest way then using following code you can set the width and height.
there are two options indeed.
first u may want to use inline css to edit this like

```
document.getElementById("your image's id").style.width="285px";
document.getElementById("your image's id").style.height="143px";
```

or you may want just to use html attributes those i dont recommend

```
document.getElementById("your image's id").width="285px";
document.getElementById("your image's id").height="143px";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add height and width using style attribute

```
$html .= '<img class="' . esc_attr( $args['thumb_align'] ) . ' rpwe-thumb" src="' . esc_url( $image ) . '" alt="' .  esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '" style="heigth:143px; width:285px;">';
```

**OR**

```
$html .= '<img class="' . esc_attr( $args['thumb_align'] ) . ' rpwe-thumb" src="' . esc_url( $image ) . '" alt="' .  esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '"  heigth="143px" width="285px">';
```

This might help you

Comment: This is not better than to do in in normal way: `<img src="..." width="..." height="...">`.

Comment: i have updates my answer and add both of the option for user because both will work in this case